# Does the order of LINQ functions matter?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Basically, as the question states... does the order of LINQ functions matter in terms of **performance**? Obviously the results would have to be identical still...

Example:

```
myCollection.OrderBy(item => item.CreatedDate).Where(item => item.Code > 3);
myCollection.Where(item => item.Code > 3).OrderBy(item => item.CreatedDate);
```

Both return me the same results, but are in a different LINQ order. I realize that reordering some items will result in different results, and I'm not concerned about those. What my main concern is in knowing if, in getting the same results, ordering can impact performance. And, not just on the 2 LINQ calls I made (OrderBy, Where), but on any LINQ calls.

Comment: It is even more obvious the provider's optimisation matters with a more pedantic case like `var query = myCollection.OrderBy(item => item.Code).Where(item => item.Code == 3);`.

Comment: @GibboK: Be careful when attempting to "optimize" your LINQ queries (see answer below). Sometimes you don't end up actually optimizing anything. It's best to use a profiler tool when attempting optimization.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

It will depend on the LINQ provider in use. For LINQ to Objects, that could certainly make a *huge* difference. Assume we've actually got:

```
var query = myCollection.OrderBy(item => item.CreatedDate)
                        .Where(item => item.Code > 3);

var result = query.Last();
```

That requires the *whole* collection to be sorted and *then* filtered. If we had a million items, only one of which had a code greater than 3, we'd be wasting a lot of time ordering results which would be thrown away.

Compare that with the reversed operation, filtering first:

```
var query = myCollection.Where(item => item.Code > 3)
                        .OrderBy(item => item.CreatedDate);

var result = query.Last();
```

This time we're only ordering the filtered results, which in the sample case of "just a single item matching the filter" will be a lot more efficient - both in time and space.

It also *could* make a difference in whether the query executes correctly or not. Consider:

```
var query = myCollection.Where(item => item.Code != 0)
                        .OrderBy(item => 10 / item.Code);

var result = query.Last();
```

That's fine - we know we'll never be dividing by 0. But if we perform the ordering *before* the filtering, the query will throw an exception.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Is there documentation about the Big-O for each of the LINQ Providers and functions? Or is this merely a case of "each expression is unique to the situation".

Comment: @michael: It's not very clearly documented, but if you read my "Edulinq" blog series I think I talk about it in reasonable detail.

Comment: One note I feel obligated to make is that it's also important how you modify the query.  For example, calling .OrderBy(x => x.Code).OrderBy(x => x.Name) is incorrect - you would instead call .OrderBy(x => x.Code).ThenBy(x => x.Name).

Comment: The LINQ library doesn't build the expression tree in the reasonable  order (from => where => select) No matter how do I chain the method? If it's not implemented that way, it's a waste.

Comment: @gdoron: It's not really clear what you mean, to be honest. Sounds like you might want to write a new question. Bear in mind that Queryable isn't trying to *interpret* your query at all - its job is *solely* to preserve your query so that something else can interpret it. Also note that LINQ to Objects doesn't even use expression trees.

Comment: Sorry. I will rephrase, If I write a LINQ to SQL query, it doesn't matter the order of the LINQ method- `projections` because when I Run the query, SQL query will built according to the expression tree. Why it doesn't work this way with LINQ to Entities? when I enumerate an IQueryable all the `projections` can be placed in a rational order(e.g. Order By after Where) Shall I ask this question in a new post?

Comment: @gdoron: The point is that's the provider's job, not Queryable's job. And it shouldn't matter when using Entity Framework, either. It *does* matter for LINQ to Objects though. But yes, by all means ask another question.

Comment: Asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595258/why-the-order-of-linq-to-objects-methods-counts) Thanks!!!

Comment: To save future devs from the inconvenience of having to google in response to a broken link: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/

Answer (score 17):

Yes.

But exactly *what* that performance difference is depends on how the underlying expression tree is evaluated by the LINQ provider.

For instance, your query may well execute faster the second time (with the WHERE clause first) for LINQ-to-XML, but faster the first time for LINQ-to-SQL.

To find out precisely what the performance difference is, you'll most likely want to profile your application. As ever with such things, though, premature optimisation is not usually worth the effort -- you may well find issues other than LINQ performance are more important.

Answer (score 5):

In your particular example it *can* make a difference to the performance.

First query: Your `OrderBy` call needs to iterate through the *entire* source sequence, including those items where `Code` is 3 or less. The `Where` clause then also needs to iterate the *entire* ordered sequence.

Second query: The `Where` call limits the sequence to only those items where `Code` is greater than 3. The `OrderBy` call then only needs to traverse the reduced sequence returned by the `Where` call.

Answer (score 3):

**In Linq-To-Objects:**

Sorting is rather slow and uses `O(n)` memory. `Where` on the other hand is relatively fast and uses constant memory. So doing `Where` first will be faster, and for large collections significantly faster.

The reduced memory pressure can be significant too, since allocations on the  large object heap(together with their collection) are relatively expensive in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously the results would have to be identical still...

Note that this is not actually true - in particular, the following two lines will give different results (for most providers/datasets):

```
myCollection.OrderBy(o => o).Distinct();
myCollection.Distinct().OrderBy(o => o);
```

Comment: No, what I meant was that the results should be identical to even consider optimization. There is no point in "optimizing" something and getting a different result.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that you should be careful when considering *how* to optimize a LINQ query. For example, if you use the declarative version of LINQ to do the following:

```
public class Record
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Score1 { get; set; }
    public double Score2 { get; set; }
}


var query = from record in Records
            order by ((record.Score1 + record.Score2) / 2) descending
            select new
                   {
                       Name = record.Name,
                       Average = ((record.Score1 + record.Score2) / 2)
                   };
```

If, for whatever reason, you decided to "optimize" the query by storing the average into a variable first, you wouldn't get the desired results:

```
// The following two queries actually takes up more space and are slower
var query = from record in Records
            let average = ((record.Score1 + record.Score2) / 2)
            order by average descending
            select new
                   {
                       Name = record.Name,
                       Average = average
                   };

var query = from record in Records
            let average = ((record.Score1 + record.Score2) / 2)
            select new
                   {
                       Name = record.Name,
                       Average = average
                   }
            order by average descending;
```

---

I know not many people use declarative LINQ for objects, but it is some good food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the relevancy. Suppose if you have very few items with Code=3, then the next order will work on small set of collection to get the order by date.

Whereas if you have many items with the same CreatedDate, then the next order will work on larger set of collection to get the order by date.

So, in both case there will be a difference in performance